# Allure report with robotframework is showing html file without the test run results

Tags: robotframework, allure

I am running tests with robot framework and i want to get allure report. I have been able to successfully install it and i can see that the .xml files are getting created with the test run results. But when i do "Allure serve " it displays a report without any test information in it.

Can someone please help me? I am using AllureReportLibrary in the robotframework

Comment: I updated the Allure Adapter version to 2.3.1 and it started working fine.

Comment: So, the issue is now resolved? If this is something that is of use to other, write an answer and mark it in three days.

Comment: Yes, the allure adapater version in the configuration file should be the same as the version installed. It works then,

Answer (score 0):

share one lession.

```
robot --listener allure_robotframework  CustomerService.robot
```

Default output directory is output/allure.

```
allure generate output  --clean
```

where I use this command to generate report, no testcase in report.

```
allure generate output/allure  --clean
```

when I change to this dir, it works. So I guess the innermost directory is necessary.